# Adding forward with windsor facility

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I have a windsor facility that I need to use to add a forward to a registered component. For some reason I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I have the `ComponentRegistered` event bound and I'm able to filter out what I need to add the additional interface to but I can't seem to add the forward. Here is what I have in my facility:

```
void KernelComponentRegistered(string key, IHandler handler)
{
    if (typeof(ICanDoMagic).IsAssignableFrom(handler.ComponentModel.Implementation))
    {
        // I don't know what goes here
    }
}
protected override void Init()
{
    Kernel.ComponentRegistered += KernelComponentRegistered;
}
```

and I have the following interfaces and class:

`public interface ICanDoMagic`

`public interface IBasicInterface`

`public class BasicClass : IBasicInterface, ICanDoMagic`

and here is the registration with windsor

`container.Register(Component.For<IBasicInterface>().ImplementedBy<BasicClass>())`

What I want to have happen is when the user registers things that implement ICanDoMagic (like I have in the registration above) I want to also register the ICanDoMagic interface for that class so they don't need to register it themselves. I think this is done with a forward but I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Have you considered using the [`AllInterfaces()`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx#_AllInterfaces__8) descriptor instead? Or is this specific to just the `ICanDoMagic` interface?

Comment: ICanDoMagic is supposed to be a behaviour in this example so I would need it specific to ICanDoMagic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to attach to `Kernel.ComponentModelCreated` instead.  This code will then work for you:

```
void KernelComponentModelCreated(ComponentModel model)
{
    if (typeof(ICanDoMagic).IsAssignableFrom(model.Implementation))
    {
        model.AddService(typeof(ICanDoMagic));
    }
}
```

This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938898/castle-windsor-how-can-i-update-a-components-registration).